# Styling a wordpress widget title

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now. How do I style my widget title to have this horizontal line besides my widget title and not under it. Like so:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWTIL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the CSS Editor in WordPress, then just use the pseudo class `:after` to add that underline beside the widget title.

You can see the working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/j835Lbg2/3/

```css
/* just an example widget */
.widget {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.widget-title {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  padding: 12px 12px;
}

/* widget title text */
.widget-title > .widget_name {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* widget underline beside the title */
.widget_dash:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-title">
    <span class="widget_name">WIDGET TITLE</span>
    <span class="widget_dash"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-title">
    <span class="widget_name">ANOTHER WIDGET</span>
    <span class="widget_dash"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I'm quite new to wordpress I don't even know how I'd add those two span classes to my code which looks something like this as of the moment: `<div class="widget widget_text" id="text-11"><p class="title-s title-widget title-widget-blue">Latest Videos</p>   <div class="textwidget"></div>`

Comment: @R.Mclaren, if you are not able to add additional tags inside the widget, then use this: https://jsfiddle.net/j835Lbg2/4/. It works with your existing Widget code.

Answer (score 2):

Open your current activated theme. Then find registered sidebar function.
There is the attribute before_title etc in `register_sidebar` function.

You can change the class assigned there. The change will however apply to all widgets in the same widget area (which may be a benefit or problem).

Example:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use your developer inspect tool *([firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools))*, locate
  the widget and it's selector.
- Then simply apply your custom styles to this relevant selector you found *( ie. it's title)*.
- If it does *not* have a unique selector, or a selector for the
  particular area you want to style. Navigate through your theme's
  files and locate the widgets `php` code or it's include mark-up area, add a
  unique selector directly in there, that you could then style to your
  preference.
- Or, if you really must; you could add the selector with jQuery or
  javaScript and then style it. *ie,* `$('widget').addClass('customWidget');`

Hope this helps!